# Is there a Json4S serializer that automatically corrects type error caused by XML to JSON conversion?

Tags: xml, json4s

I'm using json4s to simplify data serialization/deserialization process.

The handling for XML in json4s is native, yet incomplete. Namely, XML doesn't distinguish numeric type from String, or primitive field from array field with single element.

However, these type information can be retrieved from Java/Scala reflection, yet for unknown reason, json4s choose to fail fast when correcting such simple error is possible, is there an existing implementation that can automatically correct these errors?

A simple implementation is to customize a "weakly typed" or "insensitive" Serializer. E.g. when a JInt is expected for a class constructor (or even better case class field) yet a JString is found, or vice versa, it can do a typecast first and only fails when it is impossible.

I'm using json4s 3.2.10 so apology if such feature is already included in latest version